# Date validation using moment js not working

Tags: angularjs, typescript, momentjs

I am trying to validate a date that using moment in typescript. But it gives a wrong output. Though I provide an array of different date formats and giving a date according to these date formats, the validation always returns false.

**HTML**

`

```
<p-calendar [ngModel]="author.birthDate | momentToDateString" 
[inline]="false" [required]="true"
name="inpBirthDate" #birthDate="ngModel" [showIcon]="true" 
[maxDate]="maxDate" (ngModelChange)="author.birthDate = $event" 
[dateFormat]="dateFormat"
(onInput)="author.birthDate = dateTimeUpdate($event)"            
[monthNavigator]="appConsts.calendarSettings.monthNavigator"
[yearNavigator]="appConsts.calendarSettings.yearNavigator"
[yearRange]="appConsts.calendarSettings.yearRange">
</p-calendar>
```

`

**TS**

`

```
dateTimeUpdate(event, isTime = false) {
    const expectedFormat = isTime ? 
    this.appConsts.expectedDateTimeFormat : 
    this.appConsts.expectedDateFormat;

    const date = event.target.value;

    if (
        event !== null && event !== undefined &&
        date !== null &&date !== undefined && date !== ''
    ) {

        let formatedDate = moment(date, expectedFormat, true);

        if (formatedDate.isValid()) {
            return formatedDate.toDate();
        }
    }

    return '';
}
```

`

**expectedDateFormat**

`

```
['dd-MM-YY', 'd-MM-YY']
```

`

**expectedDateTimeFormat**

`

```
['dd-MM-YY, h:mm:ss a', 'd-MM-YY, h:mm:ss a']
```

`

as function parameter `isTime` is false, then expectedDateFormat will be selected, though I give a date like `10-03-21`, it returns false

Answer (score 0):

I was giving the wrong formatted date. this code is workable